# rtf - table column hidden

Tags: rtf

The following code only displays the first column:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0
\trowd
\paperw15840\paperh12240\margl720\margr720\margt720\margb720
\cellx4000
\cellx3000
blagshfshsfhsfhsfhs \intbl\cell
blagshfshsfhsfhsfhs \intbl\cell
}
```

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

In RTF, `\cellx` represents the x position in twips of the end of the table cell. Here, you are defining that the 2nd table cell should end 1000 twips before the first table cell. Also, your RTF is invalid, as it is missing a `\row` terminator.

You should use the following if you want a cell of 4000 twips and a cell of 3000 twips:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0
\trowd
\paperw15840\paperh12240\margl720\margr720\margt720\margb720
\cellx4000
\cellx7000
\intbl blagshfshsfhsfhsfhs \cell
blagshfshsfhsfhsfhs \cell\row
}
```